# Travel to Macau from Hong Kong Airport via Ferry

Tags: indian-citizens, hong-kong, macau

I am travelling to Macau with friends. We land at Hong Kong. Will we need to get any kind of visa for Hong Kong (Indian Nationals require PAR/ Visa) if we want to directly transit to Macau via the ferry?